# Was there any early church fathers who affirmed the Death Penalty?

Tags: church-history, early-church, church-fathers, capital-punishment

The death penalty is clearly supported in the scriptures (Genesis 9:6, Exodus 21:12, Numbers 35:30-31, Deuteronomy 17:6, Job 19:29, Romans 13:1-4) but was there any Early Church Fathers between 80 AD to 900 AD who believed and affirmed the concept of the death penalty?

> Whoso sheddeth man's blood, by man shall his blood be shed: for in the
> image of God made he man.

**Genesis 9:6**

> He that smiteth a man, so that he die, shall be surely put to death.

**Exodus 21:12**

> Whoso killeth any person, the murderer shall be put to death by the
> mouth of witnesses: but one witness shall not testify against any
> person to cause him to die.
>
> Moreover ye shall take no satisfaction for the life of a murderer,
> which is guilty of death: but he shall be surely put to death

**Numbers 35:30-31**

> At the mouth of two witnesses, or three witnesses, shall he that is
> worthy of death be put to death; but at the mouth of one witness he
> shall not be put to death

**Deuteronomy 17:6**

> Be ye afraid of the sword: for wrath bringeth the punishments of the
> sword, that ye may know there is a judgment

**Job 19:29**

Let every soul be subject unto the higher powers. For there is no power but of God: the powers that be are ordained of God.

Whosoever therefore resisteth the power, resisteth the ordinance of God: and they that resist shall receive to themselves damnation.

For rulers are not a terror to good works, but to the evil. Wilt thou then not be afraid of the power? do that which is good, and thou shalt have praise of the same:

For he is the minister of God to thee for good. But if thou do that which is evil, be afraid; for he beareth not the sword in vain: for he is the minister of God, a revenger to execute wrath upon him that doeth evil.

**Romans 13:1-4**

Comment: You've basically already asked this before. Please search before asking new questions.

Comment: The Apostle Paul implies he agrees with the death penalty in Acts 25:11.